# pushViewController does nothing when I call it

Tags: ios

I'm trying to get my app to go to the next screen.  I eneded up creating a simple test app with 2 screens

On the first vue I have a button connected to the following code to call up the next screen

```
- (IBAction)atest:(id)sender {

    if (mHome == nil)
        mHome = [[cHome  alloc] initWithNibName:@"cHome" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mHome animated:YES];
}
```

I put a break point to make sure the code exicutes, it does but..... the next screen does not come up.

complete code

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface cHome : UIViewController{

}
- (IBAction)atest:(id)sender;
@end

@interface cHome ()

@end

@implementation cHome

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}


- (IBAction)atest:(id)sender
{
  [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: Try using a new UINavigationController object instead of self.navigationController in your button function call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like to add onto Unkn0wn and demonstrate how I presented certain views in an app.

- Add a storyboard id for your view controller

  - click on your view controller in your storyboard hierarchy
  - click the identity inspector
  - add a storyboard id as a string in the storyboard id box

I then did something like this in my code:

```
[self presentViewController:[self.storyboard nstantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Paint"] animated:NO completion:nil];
```

obviously, your identifier would not be "Paint" but that's what I used.  This was my simplist approach, hope it helps good luck!

NOTE: I did not use navigation controllers in my app.

***EDIT***

would like to point out, that this method kind of makes the controller appear out of nowhere with no animation (I had special animation for my controls as a transition between view controllers so I didn't need to animate the controller itself)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push a view controller, you can easily create a push segue, from your first view controller to your second view controller, and then push using

`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueIdentifier" sender:self];`

"push segues" can be created both via code or in your storyboard file.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your code:

`mHome = [[cHome  alloc] initWithNibName:@"cHome" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];`

I think it's the nib name. It should be mHome not cHome.

`mHome = [[cHome  alloc] initWithNibName:@"mHome" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];`

You basically **cannot** push two of the same view controller on one navigation controller.